# How to run Mongo JS Shell Script with DB Connection

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, shell

I'm trying to write a mongo shell script that will delete some entries in an existing DB, and then reload them (depending on some conditions), and I'm having a lot of trouble.

One thing I can't understand/figure out is this:
To run the script file I'm making (let's call it script.js), I'm reading (from [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) and other places) that I need to use a command like this:

```
mongo mongodb://{{mycreds}}@{{address of existing mongo}}:27017/{{DB I want}}?authSource=admin script.js
```

However, since I'm connecting to that same DB in the script itself, I'm also seeing that I need to make that connection in the script.js:

```
db = connect(
  "mongodb://{{mycreds}}@{{address where the existing mongo is}}:27017/{{DB I want}}?authSource=admin"
);
```

Why do I have to specify the DB connection when running the script? It's in the script?

Either way, I'm not able to make the connection in the script. I don't know if I'm running the script incorrectly, or making the connection to the DB in the script incorrectly. Or just something else.

In the docs, it says I can run the script in the mongo shell as well. But don't I have to have a mongo instance running at 27017 to start the script? And do I need a mongo running on my machine (since there's already one that exists that I need to connect to)?

I would really appreciate some clarity in this. All I'm trying to figure out is how to run a mongo script that connects to an existing DB, and I'm getting really tangled in all these docs.

Edit:

After receiving a comment (thanks Joe), I removed the connection in the script file and was able to make the connection. I guess having both was messing it up. I'd still like to be able to have the connection in the script, but not when I run the script.
I want to do this so that others can run the script without entering the long connection address.

If anyone knows a way to do this, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to `connect` again inside the script.  Have you tried without that?

Comment: I tried removing that from the script, and it worked. I guess having both was messing it up. I'd like to be able to have the connection in the script, but not when I run the script. However, I suppose this way works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you always need a credential for any DB you want to connect even if it's SQL. if you want to make it easier for you, you need to create a file.js in vs code and put a credential in a file when you need it you can just call it that's it, and use roboMongo to make your life easier with MongoDB.

Comment: That credentials file is a good idea, but this isn't a credentials issue. Turns out having a connection in the script, while also making the connection when running the script lead to issues. So, I've removed the connection in the script, and it's working now. I would still like to be able to have the connection in the script, but not when I run the script. However, I suppose this way works. Thanks